# FindAsync not work for MockDbcontext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to do mock test for entity framework. In my method all are working well. The problem is, in my method I am trying to find the user in the list using `FindAsync`. I pass the user id through my method and then I am trying to get that user from that list.

Here is my List:

```
private static List<PersonnelInfo> personnelModelList = new List<PersonnelInfo>()
    {
        new PersonnelInfo{Id = 14, CreatedBy = 3, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, DataJSON = "{}", ApprovalState = 1, DataStatus = 3,EffectiveDate=DateTime.Now,LocaleId = 3, User = new User(){ ID = 2}, Locale = new Locale(){LocaleID = 1 } },
        new PersonnelInfo{Id = 2,  CreatedBy = 2, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, DataJSON = "{}", ApprovalState = 2, DataStatus = 2, EffectiveDate=DateTime.Now, LocaleId =2, User = new User(){ ID = 1},Locale = new Locale(){LocaleID = 2 } }
    };
```

This is the `FindAsync` that I used inside my method:

```
PersonnelInfo pInfo = await dbContext.PersonnelInfoes.FindAsync(id);
```

Here, `pInfo` is always null. I am trying to find the user where `Id = 2`.

Comment: doesn't 'dbContext' search somewhere in the database for what you're looking for when you really have to be grabbing it from the list? 

Also, your pinfo has a typo. You're writing PersonnelInfoes when it's PersonnelInfo

Comment: 1) MVC has nothing to do with EF 2) Where's the mocking code? How did you replace `dbContext.PersonnelInfoes` with `personnelModelList `? Are you using a specific mocking framework? Did you *configure* it to use your data when you call `FindAsync` ?